# Mdadm raid 5 array is half the size than expected

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I crated a Raid 5 array with mdadm consisting of 4 x 4TB drives, i was expecting the array to be 11-12Tb in total space.

But after building the array I noticed it is actuall half the size of the expected size at only 6TB. And each drive is showing as 2tb usable.

Raid config:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md127 : active raid5 sdc1[1] sda1[4] sdd1[2] sdb1[0]
      6442051584 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 1/16 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>

$ mdadm --detail /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Jul 25 10:24:33 2023
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 6442051584 (6143.62 GiB 6596.66 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 2147350528 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sat Aug  5 00:10:25 2023
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 4
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : explorer:0  (local to host explorer)
              UUID : bd6ea5b8:e20be480:40c7cf15:514e6dec
            Events : 2734

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       4       8        1        3      active sync   /dev/sda1
```

all the disks used in the array

```
$ fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdd: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: HGST HUS724040AL
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x93cf7f24

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 4294967295 4294965248   2T fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/sdb: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: HGST HUS724040AL
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x35a7a3cc

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 4294967295 4294965248   2T fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/sda: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: HGST HUS724040AL
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfa31510a

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 4294967295 4294965248   2T fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/sdc: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: HGST HUS724040AL
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x584e9ded

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 4294967295 4294965248   2T fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/md127: 6 TiB, 6596660822016 bytes, 12884103168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1572864 bytes
```

It doesnt make sense why the raid would be half the size id expect it to be.

How can i figure out why this is the case and/or get the full size expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For RAID5 you use partitions with size of 2T (check `fdisk` output)

> Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type /dev/sdb1
> 2048 4294967295 4294965248   **2T** fd Linux raid autodetect

so this size is expected. Use entire disks and you will get bigger result array.

As mentioned in comment seems like you use MBR tables. Switch to GPT to be able to create bigger partitions.

Comment: This is because MBR partition table (`Disklabel type: dos`) doesn't support anything bigger. Always use GPT partition table with devices larger than 2T. Also, if boot with `grub` from GPT disk is needed, it is essential to have an empty 1 MiB partition of type `bios boot` (type 4 in fdisk, as I can recall).

Comment: Ok, that make sense, I have destroyed the raid and rebuilding it with GPT partitioning.

Comment: @DrWhat, if you find my answer helpful and it answer your question you may accept the answer (the tick on the left from answer body)

Comment: I have, I was waiting for the raid to build to make sure that it was the correct answer.